# Approximating a Poisson distribution using a partially observed Gaussian

Tags: distributions, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, distance-functions

*Note that the problem specification has changed since the original posting.  Thanks to whuber for helping me better specify the question: in an attempt to make the question general, I had left out several important constraints.*

**Problem**: Let $y$ be distributed Poisson with rate parameter $\lambda$:

$p(y | \lambda) = \frac{\lambda^y}{y!}e^{-\lambda}$

Let $z^*$ be distributed Gaussian with mean $\mu$ and variance $1$:

$p(z^* | \mu) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{(z^* - \mu)^2}{2}}$

Define $z$ as follows:

$z = k$ if $\gamma_{k} \le z^* < \gamma_{k+1} $, where $\gamma_0 = -\infty$.

Let $\mu = \log\lambda$.  How do we choose a single sequence of $\gamma_k$ for $k = 1, 2, \ldots, \infty$, that does not depend on $\lambda$, in order to best approximate the distribution of $y$ with the distribution of $z$, across the full range of possible values of $\lambda \in (0,\infty)$.  It is not clear to me exactly what the right criterion is here for operationalizing "best approximating" across the full range of $\lambda$.

**Background**: The idea here is to do something similar to the Albert and Chib (1993) approach to Gibbs sampling binary and categorical models.  Instead of having a single or small number of cutpoints, here we would have an infinite series of cutpoints.  The question is how to choose the cutpoints to best approximate a Poisson distribution.  As a practical matter, it is pretty easy to draw doubly-truncated normal random variates (Robert 2009).

There is an existing approach to using data augmentation to fit a Poisson regression (Frühwirth-Schnatter and Wagner 2005), but it seems to involve rapidly increasing computation with increasing values of the count variable, which is a very unattractive feature for my application.

I am working on a Gibbs sampler for a hierarchical model to be applied to a very large dataset of count data.  I have no particular reason to believe that the distribution of counts are particularly close to Poisson, I am mostly interested in computational efficiency and not having a probability distribution for the counts that is very far from a standard distribution.

**References:**

[James H. Albert and Siddhartha Chib, "Bayesian Analysis of Binary and Polychotomous Response Data"](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~brian/905-2009/all-papers/albert-chib-1993.pdf)

[Sylvia Frühwirth-Schnatter and Helga Wagner, "Data Augmentation and Gibbs Sampling for Regression Models of Small Counts"](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jku.at%2Fifas%2Fcontent%2Fe108280%2Fe146255%2Fe146306%2Fifasrp04_2004.pdf&ei=Dk3dUZG9GZKo0wWX4IC4AQ&usg=AFQjCNGG5lMcynWyra-c4ENWG9wdiTH7Lw&sig2=klSBWzHdAfrlygkPOIUsrA&bvm=bv.48705608,d.d2k)

[Christian Robert, "Simulation of truncated normal variables"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.4010.pdf)

Comment: Aren't you just asking for the Gaussian cutpoints needed to match the Poisson probabilities? That is, letting $F$ be the CDF of *any* continuous distribution--which could include any Gaussian you like--you are requiring $F(\gamma_{k+1}) - F(\gamma_k) = p(k|\lambda)$, which immediately gives the full solution inductively. Given the length of your exposition I figure there must be something more going on here, but what is it?

Comment: Maybe that is the answer.  I had thought that was the solution, but then I convinced myself that there must be something wrong with that approach.  But now I can't remember why I thought that would not do what I wanted.  Let me see if I can work out the solution along those lines, I will post it if I can...  or clarify the issue if I cannot...

Comment: Ok, I think I left out an important constraint in specifying the question, which is that the sequence of $\gamma$ values must be the same, regardless of what $\lambda$ is for the desired distribution.  Since the idea is to create a partial observability process in which the random realization of a gaussian (with some values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$) is observed as a count, I think the cutpoints have to be constant.

Comment: That sounds hopeless unless you have some constraints on $\lambda$. Even then, you need to stipulate the objective: to minimize the greatest possible deviation? To minimize an expected deviation based on a prior distribution for $\lambda$? The values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are irrelevant, by the way, because a solution $(\gamma_k)$ for a standard Gaussian will give the same results as the solution $(\sigma\gamma_k+\mu)$ for the general Gaussian. You might as well just set $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$ once and for all.